# Notation of portamento

Tags: notation, glissando

I have two measures (in treble clef) of a soprano voice, the first starting on the higher c and the second ending on the c an octave lower.

I would like to notate a portamento that starts on the beginning of measure 1 and ends on the end of measure 2.

This is my current notation:

[image]

Is my notation correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have at present is vague about whether the gliss starts early or late, but is pretty clear that it ends on the FIRST beat of bar 2.

For clarity of exactly where the gliss starts and ends, I think you want something like this.  Rests to show the beats?  Or no rests because - well, there ISN'T silence!   Maybe even my third example, though I can see it being a rehearsal-stopper.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

**IMO your example is clear** and conveys that the glissando should start at the beginning of m1 and ends at the end of m2.

If you would want something different, then it would be notated differently, I think.

E.g. you want the glissando to start at the *last beat of m1* until the end of m2:
[image]

Or you want the glissando to start at the beginning of m1 until *the first beat of m2*:
[image]

Comment: Nope, my interpretation of the example agrees with Laurence Payne's: the glissando ends at the *beginning* of Bar 2.

Comment: Ok, fair enough @Dekkadeci

Comment: But TBH I wouldn't interpret Laurence's notations correctly either. I'd be very confused by all of them.

Comment: The OP wants the gliss to end on the final beat of measure 2.  I don't think you can indicate this without putting rests or "empties" in the first 3 beats of that measure.